# undefined reference to boost serialization functions

Tags: c++, qt, boost

and using boost serialization I have been getting a lot of errors using the serialization header files, like this:

> /home/saikumar/Downloads/boost_1_61_0/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:117: error: undefined reference to `boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl::text_iarchive_impl(std::istream&, unsigned int)'

I tried every possible links in stackoverflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480765/boost-with-qt-creator-and-linux), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410942/undefined-reference-to-boostsystemsystem-category), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200911/undefined-reference-to-boostsystemgeneric-category-with-qt), and several others).

They say to use `LIBS += -lboost_system` or others but boost documentation says it is a header only library [Boost setup](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html), which means it doesn't require any library linkage and even if I try searching for that library in boost folder, I can not find it.

I followed the same steps performed in boost setup process but I am not able to find any thing. Here is the code that i am testing it on:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <vector>

class test
{
public:

    std::vector<int> test1;
    std::string test2;

    test()
    {
    }

    test(std::vector<int> h, std::string i):test1(h), test2(i)
    {
    }
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & test1;
        ar & test2;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    test obj;

    obj.test1.push_back(1);
    obj.test1.push_back(3);
    obj.test1.push_back(6);
    obj.test1.push_back(74);
    obj.test1.push_back(43);
    obj.test1.push_back(12);
    obj.test1.push_back(8);
    obj.test1.push_back(13);

    obj.test2 ="jsahdjfkadshflkssfjdslfk";


    std::ofstream file("myfile.FILE");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oo(file);
    oo<<obj;

    test obj1;

    std::ifstream ifs("myfile.FILE");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> obj1;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp` is part of [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) and that definitely is **not** a header-only library.

The library is normally called `boost_serialization` (`libboost_serialization.so`), plus you also need `boost_wserialization` (`libboost_wserialization.so`) if you want to use `wchar_t` with it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to link against boost::serialization. Add `-lboost_serialization` to your LIBS.

```
LIBS += -lboost_serialization
```